# How to handle / remove broken image icon of imagebutton in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add alternate image if the image is broken, also can we remove the broken image icon? Here is my code:

```
<asp:ImageButton 
    AlternateText = " " 
    onerror = "imgError(this)" 
    ID = "ImageButton111" 
    runat="server" 
    Width = "140" 
    Height = "140" 
    CommandName = "image1" 
    CssClass = "imagetest" 
    CommandArgument = "image"  
    CausesValidation = "false" 
    ImageUrl='<%# "loadImage.ashx?RollNo=" + Eval("RollNO")%>' 
/>



    function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "~/images/no-hit.gif";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Since the image is downloaded by the client, I don't think there is much you can do server-side. Maybe look in to handleing this client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think AlternateText itself is a built-in feature for setting a text in place of image in case image could not be loaded properly.

Or, If you want an alternate image, use this:

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="changeImage('alternate_image.gif')">
```

And set the alternate image in the javascript function:

```
function changeImage(altImage){
$(this).attr('src',altImage.toString());
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the onerror event and implement it in your CodeBehind. That way, if JavaScript is disabled, you will still get the desired results. I used HttpWebRequest. It's only checking the HEAD, so it isn't actually downloading the file, it's just checking to see if the image is accessible.

```
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(ImageButton1.ImageUrl);
    request.Method = "HEAD";

    try
    {
        request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch
    {

        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "yournewimage.jpg";
    }
```

Comment: I am not able to access the imageButton in code behind as it is nested inside itemtemplate in datalist.

Comment: You can access controls inside ItemTemplates. Just so we don't stray off topic here, just do a search for "Access control inside itemtemplate" and you'll come up with stuff. I actually try and stay away from those types of controls for this very reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your datalist markup like this, the place where you are creating the image

```
<%
    string filePath = "loadImage.ashx?RollNo=" + Eval("RollNo");
    if (IsImageValid(filePath))
    {
    %>
      <asp:ImageButton AlternateText=" " ID="ImageButton111" runat="server"
          Width="140" Height="140" CommandName="image1" CssClass="imagetest" CommandArgument = "image"
    CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl='<%# "loadImage.ashx?RollNo=" + Eval("RollNO")%>' />
   <%}
      else
   {%>
     <asp:ImageButton AlternateText=" " ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"
        Width="140" Height="140" CommandName="image1" CssClass="imagetest" CommandArgument="image"
         CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/images/no-hit.gif" />
  <%} %>
```

Now what you will be doing is, creating a different image if image is broken

And IsImageValid function can be defined like this

```
public bool IsImageValid(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        System.Drawing.Image newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename);
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
    {
        // Image.FromFile will throw this if file is invalid.
        // Don't ask me why.
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This all can be done in OnItemDataBound event also, even with more ease.

Comment: Getting exception buddy "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control."